# Validators not working Symfony2.1

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, symfony-2.1

I have a problem with validators. My form is always valid also if i enter invalid data.
My validator does not seem to be considered.

The code:

//validation.yml

```
AskedTech\JobeetBundle\Entity\Users:
properties:
        email:
            - Email:
                message: The email "{{ value }}" is not a valid email.
                groups: [registration]
            - NotBlank: { groups: [registration] }
            - UniqueEntity: { groups: [registration] }
        password:
            - NotBlank: { groups: [registration] }
            - MinLength: { limit: 7, groups: [registration] }
        first_name:
            - NotBlank: { groups: [registration] }
        last_name:
            - NotBlank: { groups: [registration] }
```

//Controller

```
namespace AskedTech\JobeetBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use AskedTech\JobeetBundle\Entity\Users;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use AskedTech\JobeetBundle\Form\SignupType;

class UsersController extends Controller {

    public function signupAction(Request $request) {

        $users = new Users();
        $form = $this->createForm(new SignupType(), $users);

        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->bind($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {

                $post_value = $request->request->get($form->getName());

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('welcome', array('name' => $post_value['email'])));

            }
        }

        return $this->render('AskedTechJobeetBundle:Users:signup.html.twig', array(
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
                ));
    }

    public function welcomeAction($name) {
        return new Response('<html><body>Welcome in Jobeet '.$name.'!</body></html>');
    }

}
```

Form

```
namespace AskedTech\JobeetBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class SignupType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('email', 'email');
        $builder->add('first_name', 'text');
        $builder->add('last_name', 'text');
        $builder->add('email', 'text');
        $builder->add('password', 'password');
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'signup';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'AskedTech\JobeetBundle\Entity\Users',
            'validation_groups' => array('AskedTech\JobeetBundle\Entity\Users', 'registration')
        ));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> in config.yml:
>
> validation:{ enabled: true }

This did the trick for me!

Answer (score 0):

you  should connect your validation.yml file to  Bundle

in JobeetBundle\DependencyInjection\JobeetExtension add  following lines:

$yamlMappingFiles = $container->
       getParameter('validator.mapping.loader.yaml_files_loader.mapping_files');

$yamlMappingFiles[] = **DIR** . '/../Resources/config/validation.yml';
 $container->setParameter('validator.mapping.loader.yaml_files_loader.mapping_files', $yamlMappingFiles);

in config.yml:

`validation:{ enabled: true }`

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to manually connect the validation file to the bundle is it? I never had to do that. Linking to the right entity in the validation.yml file is supposed to be enough. On the other hand setting validation enabled might solve his problem.